# Flattr API gives File Not found Error

Tags: flattr

I try the following example: https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/things?id=38589

The ID Exist but I get a File Not found Error.
Something wrong in the API? I know it worked a couple of days ago.

Comment: This is what I get from that URL:{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"You are unauthorized to access the resource","error_uri":"http:\/\/developers.flattr.net\/api\/"}

Answer (score 0):

The correct URL to thing with id 38589 is https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/things/38589

And to get multiple things you separate them with a comma: 
https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/things/38589,123

I spotted a error in the documentation concerning fetching multiple things and will update it at once.